# Bulk Upload in ElasticSearch using Nest library in C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I a trying to bulk insert into ElasticSearch using BulkAll API from Nest library in C#. In order to assign an Id to each document, I am using BufferToBulk option to customize my individual documents. In general, the BulkAll finishes very fast. However, when I use BufferToBulk, it takes entire timeout time to finish. I can not figure out, what is wrong in the code below. Please note that I am using a list of dictionary objects to upload and the uploading works fine, but it is extremely slow.

```
        BulkAllObservable<Dictionary<string, object>> bulkAll = esClient.BulkAll(BatchedDocumets1, b => b
        .Index(indexName)
        .BufferToBulk((descriptor, list) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (keyindex < ListOfKeys.Count)
                {
                    descriptor.Index<Dictionary<string, object>>(bi => bi
                      .Index(indexName)
                      .Id(ListOfKeys[keyindex])
                      .Document(item)
                    );
                    keyindex++;
                }
            }
        })
        //how many retries are attempted if a failure occurs. Can be configurable.
        .BackOffRetries(2)
        //how long to wait between retries. Can be configurable
        .BackOffTime("30s")
        //refresh the index once the bulk operation completes
        .RefreshOnCompleted(true)
        .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(this.maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        .Size(this.batchSize)
        .ContinueAfterDroppedDocuments(true)
        .DroppedDocumentCallback((item, Document) =>
        {
            Logger.LogMessage(MOD.Common.Logging.LogLevel.Error, " The document can not be indexed. Bulk all indexing will be halted.");
        })
        );

        bulkAll.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
            onNext: (b) => { Logger.LogMessage(MOD.Common.Logging.LogLevel.Debug, " Next value: "); },
            onError: (e) => { throw e; },
            onCompleted: () => Logger.LogMessage(MOD.Common.Logging.LogLevel.Debug, "Bulk Upload Completed!")
        ));

        bulkAll.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), null); // We can configure this.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is ListOfKeys?  Is it just the keys of the dictionary you're uploading?  I suspect that your issue is related to that.

Comment: So, ListOfKeys is a list which has unique identifiers for each documents. I am trying to retrieve the unique ids using an index. So, it should be O(1). I can not think of a reason why it would be a problem.

Comment: because BulkAll runs in parallel, so you likely have documents overwriting eachother

Comment: So, I need very specific keys which should be assigned to the _id of each document in the bulk upload. How do you suggest I should be using those keys for the ids?

Comment: There are a few approaches you could take.  You need to make sure that you aren't duplicating keys while this is running in parallel.  The easiest way would be to assign a key to each dictionary before you call BulkAll, so just loop through BatchedDocumets1 and for each dictionary, assign a key and increment, so you're new structure would be Dict<int,Dict<string,object>>, where int is the assigned index.  Now you can safely look up on the index in paralell.

Comment: I am not sure if you meant the same, but this is what I did. My id can not be an integer because of the project requirement. So, I had to make it a string and made the dictionary as follows. See the below code example for what I did. And it is still slow. It takes the entire timeout duration to complete.

Comment: Dictionary<Dictionary<string, object>, string> ListOfKeys = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, object>, string>();

Comment: string _id = "";
                        ListOfKeys.TryGetValue(item, out _id);
                        descriptor.Index<Dictionary<string, object>>(bi => bi
                          .Index(indexName)
                          .Id(_id)
                          .Document(item)
                        );

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: How many items are you indexing and what is your maxDegreeOfParallelism set to?  Have you checked the CPU usage for your cluster?  Maybe you're just overloading it.

Comment: This is a cluster at its very initial stage. I am writing some very initial proof of concept code to upload and retrieve data. I am trying to upload 20 rows (documents) from a single file which is not at all a big thing. The CPU usage < 10%. The interesting fact is that I am facing slowness only in BufferToBulk in BulkAll. If I do not use BufferToBulk, there is no problem at all. I had to use BufferToBulk in order to assign the customized unique id. Is there any other way to assign a customized unique id? I tried creating a class with _id and the above dictionary which did not work.

Comment: I am running maxDegreeOfParallelism with 1.

Comment: what happens if you remove the .Wait method?

Comment: It looks like that worked after removing the .Wait method. It is pretty fast. What is surprising to me is that it never waited for the entire wait time when I did not use BufferToBulk. Now, is it going to be a problem if I do not use .Wait method?

Comment: You don't need the Wait method since you aren't waiting for anything.  The null parameter you've specified there is a function that gets called after the wait time.  Since Wait is a blocking operation, you're code can't continue until that finishes.  I would remove all parameters and methods and only include the ones you know you need.  The example in the docs is just showing every possible method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and all the explanations. I really appreciate it.