# Wait for bulk insert to complete

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using Nest, how can I make sure the bulk update is completed? I seem to run in to race conditions in my tests now, so I presume that's the problem:

```
var bulkRequest = new BulkRequest(ServiceIndexName)
{
    Operations = new List<IBulkOperation>()
};

// adding a lot of items here
bulkRequest.Operations.Add(new BulkIndexOperation<MyItem>(item));

elasticClient.Bulk(bulkRequest);
// I want to make sure the operation is completed here
```

Comment: You could implement an observable if you want to be notified as soon as the operation is complete, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142043/bulk-upload-in-elasticsearch-using-nest-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: You'er probably more interested into refreshing your index just after your bulk operation, it's probably why you're running into race conditions. All bulk operations have been performed when the call returns, but the index might not be completely refreshed.

Comment: @Val Correct, thanks. Please feel free to add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `elasticClient.Bulk(bulkRequest)` call returns you know for sure that all bulk operations have been executed. However, since ES operates [in near real-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/near-real-time.html), the underlying indexes might not have been refreshed yet, which might be the reason why you see race conditions in your test.

What you simply need to do is to [specify the `refresh=wait_for` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/docs-refresh.html) in your bulk call, so make sure that once it returns, everything has been executed AND everything has been refreshed.

Comment: I added `elasticClient.Indices.Refresh(ServiceIndexName);` after the bulk call. How can I do it by specifying a parameter?

Comment: Great! You probably have the option to do it inside BulkRequest

Comment: Yeah, just wanted if you knew how right off that bat. But I'll dig in to it, thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm unfortunately not a C# guy but [this might be](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/main/src/Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch/_Generated/Api/BulkRequest.g.cs#L77) what you're looking for